# Python documentation on creation of an exponential random variable

Tags: python, documentation

I didn't really know if this stack was the right place to post but I was reading [the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.exponential.html) for creating an exponential random variable in numpy. But isn't there a typo. Like shouldn't it be :

$f(x; \beta) = \frac{1}{\beta} \exp(-\frac{x}{\beta})$ instead of $f(x; \frac{1}{\beta}) = \frac{1}{\beta} \exp(-\frac{x}{\beta})$?

Comment: I'd say the correct place for this should be in their mailing list or as an issue in their github repository.

Answer (score 0):

From the [source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/7ccf0e08917d27bc0eba34013c1822b00a66ca6d/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx) on GitHub, the function does accept $\beta$, so even if expressing the function in terms of $\frac{1}{\beta}$ (rather than $\lambda=\frac{1}{\beta}$) was typical, it is a bit misleading to present it in this way on the documentation page.